# Swift 3 - Save image alternative

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, save, nsuserdefaults

I need to found an alternative of this method to save images

```
let save = UserDefaults.standard
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Photo.image!, 1.0)
save.set(imageData, forKey: "Image")
save.synchronize()
if let imgData = save.object(forKey: "Image"){
     let compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imgData as! Data)
}
```

and load images

```
let imgData = save.object(forKey: "Image")
let compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imgData as! Data)
Photo.image = compressedJPGImage
```

The problem with this method is that i have a lot of another value saved with `UserDefaults.standard` so it take a lot of time (5-10 minutes) when i synchronize.

Comment: First of all, `UserDefaults` is the last place you should store large files in. Second, `synchronize()` is mostly a non-sense. Third, you might want to use `CoreData` for image / data storing

Comment: Why do you need to save this in UserDefaults? This is not what UserDefaults should be used for.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder how can i use CoreData to save and load images ?

Comment: @totiG what should i used for save and load it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not advisable to save large files like images to UserDefaults. UserDefaults was intended to save very small data such as a user's preferred theme color of your app. Perhaps a suitable alternative is to save your images in the document directory. Here is a function that will allow you save an image:

```
    func saveImage(image: UIImage) -> String {

    let imageData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!)
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory,  FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    let docs = paths[0] as NSString
    let uuid = NSUUID().uuidString + ".png"
    let fullPath = docs.appendingPathComponent(uuid)
    _ = imageData.write(toFile: fullPath, atomically: true)
   return uuid

   }
```

The above function will create the name of the saved image for you. If you prefer to specify the name of the image you are saving then you could do the following (but you will be responsible for ensuring the image names you specify are unique):

```
    func saveImage(image: UIImage, withName name: String) {

     let imageData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!)
     let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory,  FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
     let docs = paths[0] as NSString
     let name = name
     let fullPath = docs.appendingPathComponent(name)
     _ = imageData.write(toFile: fullPath, atomically: true)
     }
```

To retrieve those images, you could pass the image name to this function:

```
     func getImage(imageName: String) -> UIImage? {

     var savedImage: UIImage?

     if let imagePath = getFilePath(fileName: imageName) {
     savedImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
     }
     else {
    savedImage = nil
     }

    return savedImage

    }
```

Which relies on this function to work:

```
    func getFilePath(fileName: String) -> String? {

    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    var filePath: String?
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
    if paths.count > 0 {
    let dirPath = paths[0] as NSString
    filePath = dirPath.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    }
   else {
    filePath = nil
   }

   return filePath
   }
```

Here is an example of how you would now save your images instead of UserDefaults. I am saving an image I will call "Image":

```
    saveImage(image: Photo.image, withName name: "Image")
```

Here is an example of how I would retrieve the saved image:

```
    if let theSavedImage = getImage(imageName: "Image") {
        //I got the image
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @gwinyai your methode is amazing but i have one problem with it ^^ when i get my image back it is turn 90 degrees left, do you know why ?

Comment: Yeah I have encountered that problem before but for some reason I do not remember the fix. Could you try save the image as JPEG with UIImageJPEGRepresentation and try it out maybe. The functions I gave you saved as PNG with UIImagePNGRepresentation. I'll just need a few to remember some details on that 90 problem.

Comment: @Rombond PNG doesn't save any orientation. You need to redraw your image prior to saving it.

Comment: @gwinyai with JPEG images it works perfectly thanks again

Comment: thanks @LeoDabus but i prefere use JPEG images its less line code ^^

Comment: Leo has explained it. I forgot that detail.

Answer (score 0):

`UserDefaults` is a place to store a small portion of data like user preferences. `UserDefaults` has very limited space and can be quite slow. In your case, you mentioned it's 5-10 minutes which I doubt though.

If you want images to be stored across the sessions of the app (persistent storage), you should consider using file system (Application_Folder/Library/Cache/) or Core Data framework. You will get better performance here while accessing the image.

If images are not needed to be persisted and need to be stored for a single session of the app, you should use the `imageNamed:` API of `UIImage` class. This API loads the image once in the memory and keeps it in the system cache. For all the successive accesses it refers to the cached image only. This will increase the system cache size and application's memory footprint if you are loading too many images. Another API is `imageWithContentsOfFile:`. Unlike the first API, this API will always load the new image instance in memory. Memory will be deallocated once image instance is released which is not the case with the first API.